# How do I test out the DEX in a standalone network?

Tags: dex

I tried reading the documentations but didn't see any sample code regarding utilizing DEX in a standalone/private network.

Any advice? Would like to simulate sending fiat currency from account A, and account B receiving it in the fiat currency it wants.

Thanks again for all the help! Been able to make progress in my learnings and I am getting so excited to try out more functionalities.

Answer (score 2):

There is actually no difference to the public network.

- Create two assets
- Create an intermediary account that holds both of them
- Create an offer from that account with [manage offer](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/list-of-operations.html#manage-offer)
- Make a [path payment](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/list-of-operations.html#path-payment) utilizing that offer to make a payment between any two accounts that have the according trustlines